# Flex Spark components not displaying

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Simple example to demonstrate the Spark Button control -->
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.events.Event;

            // Event handler function to print a message
            // describing the selected Spark Button control.
            private function printMessage(event:Event):void  {
                message.text += event.target.label + " pressed" + "\n";
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Panel title="Spark Button Control Example"
            width="75%" height="75%"
            horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:VGroup left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
            <s:VGroup width="100%">
                <s:Button label="Default Button" click="printMessage(event);"/>
                <s:Button label="autoRepeat Button" buttonDown="printMessage(event);"
                        autoRepeat="true"/>
                <s:Button label="Disabled Button" enabled="false"
                        click="printMessage(event);"/>
            </s:VGroup>
            <s:TextArea x="80" y="0" id="message" height="100%" width="100%"
                color="#0000FF"/>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Panel>

</s:Application>
```

I'am compiling it with

```
mxmlc Main.mxml
```

and then the application runs, but the window is empty, how to fix this or what can be the reason of that?, flex 4.6, all the settings are by default

Comment: Are you running it with a debug player?

Comment: I am running it with a flash player, whats wrong with that?

Comment: Ohh yes, with the debugPlayer it works fine, but what if the user will open it with a standart flash player, it will not work?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Is your debug player the same version as the normal player you use?

Comment: no the normal flash player is 10 version, and the debug is 11, so now I understand..., thank you very much for this help!!